# Getting a string text from Jsoup Element object

Tags: java, html, css, tags, jsoup

I'm trying to get a stock quote from Yahoo finance.I extract the page, find the span tag with the price quote but when i try to output it to the console nothing happens.Can anybody help?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL").get();
    Elements quote = doc.select("yfs_184_aapl");
    for(Element h: quote)
    {
        String price = h.text();
        System.out.println(price);
    }
```

I also know that the Element object is not empty:

```
if(quote == null)
    {
        System.out.println("The element is empty");
    }
```

EDIT:

I've tried this method

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL").get();
    Element quote = doc.getElementById("yfs_184_aapl");
    String price = quote.text();
    System.out.println(price);
```

It gives me null pointer exception when I try to print the price var;

Also id yfs_184_aapl is the span tag id for the stock price.If you inspect the stock price element you should be able to find it.

Comment: Please be descriptive...

Comment: I don't see any `yfs_184_aapl` tag (nor element with such class/id) in that HTML. Also `select` will not return `null` if it can't find anything, but will return empty list, so you should test it with `quote.isEmpty()`, not with `quote == null`.

Comment: Also there is a lot of JavaScript code on that page, but Jsoup doesn't support JS. Try turning off JS support in your browser and see if you will see result on page you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I had a brief look on the URL you gave. I think you mistake the css selector syntax, for the element you are looking for seems to have the id "yfs_184_aapl". You were searching for a tag with that name. So the correct query should be

```
Element quote = doc.select("#yfs_184_aapl").first();
```

Or

```
Element quote = doc.getElementById("yfs_184_aapl")
```

I did check if that content is actually loaded directly or via AJAX. You are lucky, it is already in the original content, so the should be able to  get what you need with the given alternatives.